# Child div grow to full width of parent div

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm having the issue that I want my `container` to have width 950px if possible -  but if the window is resized then it will reduce down to the size of the window accordingly, currently if the window is resized it requires horizontal scrolling to see entire `wrapper` & `container` - what am I missing?

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 950px;
  margin-right:  32px;
}

.container {
  background-color: teal;
  padding: 48px 64px 48px 64px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 414px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container"></div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `box-sizing: border-box;` to include the `padding` in the width, otherwise it will be added to the 100%, therefore exceeding the parent width.

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 950px;
  margin-right:  32px;
}

.container {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: teal;
  padding: 48px 64px 48px 64px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 414px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container"></div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine **%-based** `width` and **pixel-based** `max-width` for that, try this:

```
.wrapper {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 950px;
  margin: 0 5%;
}
```